# Junos[MX]: How to show VPLS instance associated with given subinterface

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, interface, juniper-mx, vpls

Suppose I have a subinterface with Vlan-vpls encapsulation, like this one:

```
admin@router> show configuration interfaces ge-2/1/1
flexible-vlan-tagging;
encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
unit 17 {
    encapsulation vlan-vpls;
    vlan-id 17;
}
```

Is there any command in Junos which would show me a VPLS instance associated with this subinterface (ge-2/1/1.17)?

If there are MACs in mac-table then I can use

```
show vpls mac-table interface ge-2/1/1.17
```

but what if there are no MACs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way, but you can see interfaces in the statistics:

```
user@router> show vpls statistics

[..]
Instance: EXAMPLE-VPLS-INSTANCE
   Local interface: ae2.2000, Index: 380
[..]
```

Or in the extensive flood list:

```
user@router> show vpls flood extensive
[..]
Name: EXAMPLE-VPLS-INSTANCE
[..]
    Flooding to:
    Name             Type          NhType          Index
    __all_ces__      Group          comp            1246    
        Composition: split-horizon
        Flooding to:
        Name             Type          NhType          Index
        ae2.2000         CE             ucst            1057
```

or in the extensive connections:

```
user@router> show vpls connections extensive
[..]
Instance: EXAMPLE-VPLS-INSTANCE
Edge protection: Not-Primary
  Local site: local-sites (1)
    Number of local interfaces: 1
    Number of local interfaces up: 1    
    IRB interface present: no
    ae2.2000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command `show vpls connections instance <instance-name> extensive` to view the interfaces associated with the VPLS instance .

Additional Info >> To check the MAC table , use the command `show vpls mac-table instance <instance-name>` , it will show you all the MAC addresses learnt in that VPLS instance. If you are using 'vlan-id all' knob in the VPLS instance configuration , then this command will show you MAC Table VLAN based.

To check the MAC table VLAN specific , use the command `show vpls mac-table instance <instance-name>  vlan-id  <vlan-id>`.

If you want to see the MAC table specific to some interface , you can use the command `show vpls mac-table instance <instance-name> | match <interface-name>'`

MAC learning in VPLS is only data plane based. So in case there are no MACs means no packets are forwarded to / from the CE. When CE broadcast /multicast/unicasts the packets the PE learns the MAC address just like normal LAN switch.

Comment: All your commands require an instance name, which I do not know.

Comment: @Seweryn. VPLS is a sort of BGP VPN (Multipoint to Multipoint Connectivity)  service . Just like you configure MPLS L3VPN and you want to see routes belonging to particular VPN instance you mention in the command VPN instance name. In the same way when you want to check MAC table against particular VPN (VPLS Instance) you need to mention VPLS instance name.

Comment: Yes, but the question was, how to find the instance name for a given subinterface (I see a subinterface with encapsulation vlan-vpls and there are hundreds of VPLS instances). It looks like there is no such command and I have to grep.